# Use a loop for slicing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a program where if you write in a word, let's say "Hello". And then you press the print button the outcome would be this: 
"H"
"He"
"Hel"
"Hell"
"Hello".
Should i use a loop for this? My code so far is this:

```
function printit()
{
var temptext = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
temptext = temptext.slice(1,2);

document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML=temptext;
}
```

Anyone got any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: yes you should use a loop :)

Comment: You have started well... just increment second argument of slice function, inside loop...

Comment: Instead of an ordinary loop, you could use recursion.

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter)

Comment: `var temp = document.getElementById("mytext").value, output = [];
  for (var i=0;i<=temp.length;i++) {
    output.push(temp.slice(0,i));
  }
  document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML = output.join('<br/>');`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let word = 'Good';

for (let i = 1; i <= word.length; i++) {
  console.log(word.substring(0, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how this would work with a loop.

- Loop over the characters
- Use the loop counter (`i`) to progressively `slice` the required chunk off your text.
- Make sure you `slice(0, i + 1)`, so you don't `slice(0, 0)` on the 1st iteration

```js
function print() {
  var text = document.querySelector("#text").value

  for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    console.log(text.slice(0, i + 1))
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="text" value="Hello"/>
<button onclick="print()">Print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` with a scoped variable, to return an array of the words you need

```js
function toSplicedWordArray(what) {
   var before='';
   return what.split('').map(function(item) {before+=item;return before;});
}
console.log(toSplicedWordArray('hello'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function printinit() {
  var tempText = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
  var slicedText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < tempText.length; i++) {
    slicedText = tempText.slice(0, i) + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("translated").innerHTML = temptext;
}
```

Comment: If you had made a [mcve] you would have seen it is not working. You need to concatenate to the slicedText which needs to be empty when initialised. Then show slicedText.